# Winsock: Can i call send function at the same time for different socket?

Tags: sockets, winsock

Let's say, I have a server with many connected clients via TCP, i have a socket for every client and i have a sending and receiving thread for every client. Is it safe and possible to call send function at the same time as it will not call send function for same socket.

If it's safe and ok, Can i stream data to clients simultaneously without blocking send function for other clients ?

Thank you very much for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and thread-safe. You could have tested it, or worked out for yourself that IS, IIS, SQL Server etc. wouldn't work very well if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks. you know, it's easier to ask than try it yourself with unknown result. What about my last sentence ? will be other send functions blocked when one sending ? :)

Comment: Sure - just because one thread gets blocked on send because its 'write buffer' is full, (client goes down, say), does not prevent the other threads from communicating normally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Windows from the tag of "Winsock".

This design (having a send/receive thread for every single connected client), overall, is not going to scale.  Hopefully you are aware of that and you know that you have an extremely limited number of clients (even then, I wouldn't write it this way).

You don't need to have a thread pair for every single client.

You can serve tons of clients with a single thread using non-blocking IO and read/write ready notifications (either with select() or one of the varieties of Overlapped IO such as completion routines or completion ports).  If you use completion ports you can set a pool of threads to handle socket IO and queue the work for your own worker thread or threads/threadpool.

Yes, you can send and receive to many sockets at once from different threads; but you shouldn't need those extra threads because you shouldn't be making blocking calls to send/recv at all.  When you make a non-blocking call the amount that could be written immediately is written and the function returns, you then note how much was sent and ask for notification when the socket is next writable.

I think you might want to consider a different approach as this isn't simple stuff; if you're using .Net you might get by with building this with TcpListener or HttpListener (both of which use completion ports for you), though be aware that you can't easily disable Nagle's algorithm with those so if you need interactivity (think of the auto-complete on Google's search page) then you probably won't get the performance you want.